# Optional null value with a type

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Is there a more concise way of creating an *Optional.ofNullable* of specified type without assigning it to the variable?

The working solution:

```
public Optional<V> getValue2(K key) {
    Node<K, V> node = getNode(key);
    Optional<V> nullable = Optional.ofNullable(null);
    return isNull(node) ? nullable : Optional.ofNullable(node.getValue());
}
```

Here I get an error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional to Optional"

```
public Optional<V> getValue(K key) {
    Node<K, V> node = getNode(key);
    return isNull(node) ? Optional.ofNullable(null) : Optional.ofNullable(node.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I could not clearly understand your question. Can you elaborate it like what you want to achieve, and could you please share your code as [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `return isNull(node) ? Optional.empty() : Optional.ofNullable(node.getValue());`
or
`return  Optional.ofNullable(isNull(node) ? node.getValue() : null);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, a simpler way would be:

```
public Optional<V> getValue(K key) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(getNode(key))
                   .map(Node::getValue);
}
```

If you still want to stick with what you had, you could do it with:

```
public Optional<V> getValue(K key) {
    Node<K, V> node = getNode(key);
    return isNull(node) ? 
            Optional.empty() : Optional.ofNullable(node.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Super example. The first one is great.

Comment: could also use the ternary operation inside the (unique)  ofNullable()` in the second code

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for this:

```
Optional.<V>ofNullable(null);
```

or in your case, if there is always a null passed:

```
Optional.<V>empty();
```